# Replying to Tweets Using t for the Command Line

Tags: ruby, twitter, command-line, awk

I'm using [t for Ruby](https://github.com/sferik/t) to tweet from Terminal.

I want to be able to scan my timeline, find the tweet IDs then reply to them. The closest I've got is this command that doesn't work. The issue is that the reply command takes two arguments, an ID and a message. The awk command prints out the correct ID so how to I store that to some kind of variable so I can specify where it is included in the xargs statement?

```
t timeline harryguinness -l -n 1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs t reply "This is a test"
```

I really need a way to say something like:

```
t timeline harryguinness -l -n 1 | ID = awk ‘{print $1}’ | xargs t reply ID “This is a test"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, then

```
t timeline harryguinness -l -n 1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -I ID t reply ID "This is a test"
```

should work. The `-I ID` option tells `xargs` to replace `ID` with the token read from stdin instead of appending it to the command.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks. Can people please upvote this. My reputation is too low. :/